# Download image through Parse Cloud Code function

Tags: javascript, java, android, parse-platform

I'm developing an app that deals with pictures and using `parse.com` services as a backend. At some point I had to choose between:

- store different versions of the same picture, e.g. `100x100` for thumbnails, `400x400` for bigger views, `1000x1000` for fullscreen views;
- store only the `1000x1000` version, and scale it down when needed, possibly server-side.

The solution I'm currently working on is a mixture of the two: I hold `100x100` for thumbnails, `1000x1000` for fullscreen views and would like to scale it down for any other need. I started working on a Cloud Code function to achieve this. My wish is to pass to the function the width of the current view, so to make the image adaptable to the client's need.

```
var Image = require("parse-image");

Parse.Cloud.define("getPicture", function(request, response) {

  var url = request.params.pictureUrl;
  var objWidth = request.params.width / 2;

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: url

  }).then(function(resp) {
    var i = new Image();
    return i.setData(resp.buffer);

  }).then(function(i) {
    var scale = objWidth / i.width();
    if (scale >= 1) {
        response.success(i.data());
    }
    return i.scale({
      ratio: scale
    });

  }).then(function(i) {
    return i.data();

  }).then(function(data) {
    response.success(data);
  });

});
```

I have two questions:

- is this approach correct, or should I better simply store a middle-sized version of the image (like `400x400`)? Would this determine too many calls to the cloud code function? (I'm not aware of any `parse.com` restriction for the number of cloud functions calls, but there might be)
- What kind of object is `i.data()` returning, and how can I get a `Bitmap` from it? From the Android app I'm calling:

  ```
  HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
  params.put("pictureUrl",getUrl());
  params.put("width", getWidth());
  ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getPicture", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
      @Override
      public void done(Object object, ParseException e) {

          //here I should use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(...)
          //but object is definitely not a byte[] !
          //From debugging it looks like a List<Integer>,
          //but I don't know how to get a Bitmap from it.

      }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach looks good.

Since the return value of Parse API is JSON, only way you can send binary data (an image) back is either as JSON Integer array or by using either Hex or Base64 encoded value of the binary data.

You can return `base64` string by using [Buffer#toString() method of Parse Cloud](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Buffer.html#toString) as shown below.  `base64` strings are smaller in size when compared to `hex` encoding, hence, are preferred.

```
response.success(data.toString('base64'));
```

On the Android side, code given below can be used which decodes the base 64 string into `byte[]` so that can be used in [`Bitmapfactory#decodeByteArray`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)).

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getPicture", params,
    new FunctionCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void done(String object,
                ParseException e) {

            byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decode(object, Base64.DEFAULT);
            if (imgBytes.length > 0) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);
                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view)).setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
            }
        }

    }
);
```

I have tested the changes proposed above, they work just fine.

<sub>**Note:** Please note that `R.id.image_view` is for reference purpose, you will have to use `id` of `ImageView` as applicable to your project</sub>

Comment: I used to try this but got `ClassCastException` (or something similar) saying that you can't cast `imgBytes` to `byte[]`. It should be a `List<Integer>` as far as I remember. That makes difficult to use BitmapFactory. So we should change something cloud-side, to make sure the function returns a byte[] object or something similar!

Comment: Thank you. Can't test right now but your answer looks OK. I'd just like to wait to see if some js guy comes up with a solution that does this conversion on the backend, I'd prefer to avoid working on the device.

Comment: Updated the answer to send base64 encoded value of image from server

Comment: how to upload the same?

Answer (score 0):

The answer above was correct and solved my issue, but I would be a little more careful in giving the advice of relying on "runtime-width" images. For some (most?) uses, it is definitely better to use pre-scaled images hosted on the server.

There are two issues here:

1. API requests:

Parse charges you based on the API network requests you do in a second. This is not an issue: either you call `callFunctionInBackground()`, or `loadInBackground()` from a ParseImageView, it is the same thing - one API request per call. But.

2. Caching:

If you have a server-saved ParseFile, you can cache it in a second. If you have a downloaded Bitmap that was just created for you, you can NOT cache it - not with the Parse SDK, anyway. You could try putting this ParseFile in a ParseObject and pin it, but it doesn't work - pinning requires ParseFiles to exist in the server. You could try putting the image `byte[]` in a ParseObject field, but this fails with big images and I didn't manage to make it work.

If you don't cache, things get bed soon - setting up a RecyclerView is a pain, and each time a view holder is bind, you spend a new API request.

So - I would discourage using this approach of custom-width images with adapter views and recycler views. If you go down that road, make sure you have an image caching library on your side.